# Pass variable inside nested jinja template in Airflow

Tags: bash, environment-variables, jinja2, airflow

I created a Variable (from Airflow UI):

```
Key: env_variables
Value: {'xx': 'yy`}
```

and trying to access using `var.json.env_variables.xx` inside bash operator. But the value of "xx" is dynamic, which
I am passing from REST API and accessing it using `dag_run.conf['param']` (`dag_run.conf['param']` should return `xx`). Eventually I want to run `var.json.env_variables.xx`. How can I achieve that inside bash operator in Airflow?
I am trying to run the following code but its showing Jinja Syntax Error.

```
task = BashOperator(
        bash_command="export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:{{var.json.env_variables.{{dag_run.conf['param']}} }}
```

What I want:
It should fetch the value of `var.json.env_variables.xx`. I have also tried using params but no luck, params.path is returning None.

```
task = BashOperator(
        bash_command="export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:{{params.path}},
        params: {
           "path":env_variables.get('{{dag_run.conf["param"]}}')
        }
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra `{{...}}` in the Jinja expression around `dag_run.conf` and you'll also need the typical item access of a dictionary.  Try using a template expression like this:

```py
nested_vars = BashOperator(
        task_id="nest_vars",
        bash_command="export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:{{ var.json.env_variables[dag_run.conf['param']] }}"
    )
```

This is the log entry when passing in a triggering config of `{"param": "xx"}` to the operator instantiation above:

`INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:yy']`